# Animate a css Property in Polymer 1.0

Tags: css, html, polymer, css-animations

In Polymer 0.5 you can animate a Property like this: https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/platform/web-animations.html

But how can it be done in 1.0? I'd like to animate the opacity of one of my children in my Polymer Element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`neon-animation`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/neon-animation) elements, behaviors, and animations. Here's a [guide](https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/using-neon-animations) on the basics you need to know to use them.

For opacity you can use [`fade-in-animation`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/neon-animation?active=fade-in-animation) (for opacity 0 to 1), [`fade-out-animation`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/neon-animation?active=fade-out-animation) (for opacity 1 to 0) or [`transform-animation`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/neon-animation?active=transform-animation) (to define your own to and from)